# firebase security layer and manipulations (javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I am wondering if Firebase is protected against 'scriptkiddies'.
For example: if I know the Firebase instance (from what I see in tutorials online) then I can add something to the firebase storage from my console in my browser.

```
var fbinst = new Firebase("https://nettuts-chat-application.firebaseio.com/")    
for(var i=0,l=1000;i<l;i++){fbinst.push({comment:'lol'})}
```

How can this be avoided? protected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Security Rules.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html)

Firebase Security Rules are server-side expressions that control access to your Firebase database.

Security Rules come with a **set of server variables** that allow you to check against server values. The `auth` variable contains the currently authenticated user, or `null` if there is none.

In the following sample, only authenticated users can read and write their own data.

```
{
   "rules": {
      "$uid": {
         ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
         ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
   }
}
```

Security rules allow you to read current data with the `data` variable, and the attempted data with `newData`.

```
"posts": {
   "$post_id": {
      ".read": "data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
      ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
   }
}
```

You can also validate data structure with the `.validate` rule.

```
"posts": {
   "$post_id": {
      ".read": "data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
      ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['uid'])"
   }
}
```